# ios searchbar able to add cancel image but not properly

Tags: ios, uisearchbar

In IOS searchBar i am able to add cancel image and remove text but one problem is when i searchBar Bar tint color clear after that my image is not show , and i have to clear color in tint bar for UI
i have to add image in searchbar cancel button 
Here is my code

```
-(void)searchDisplayControllerWillBeginSearch:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller{
    self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.showsCancelButton = YES;
    UIButton *cancelButton;
    UIView *topView = self.searchDisplayController.searchBar.subviews[0];
    for (UIView *subView in topView.subviews) {
        if ([subView isKindOfClass:NSClassFromString(@"UINavigationButton")]) {
            cancelButton = (UIButton*)subView;
        }
    }
    if (cancelButton) {
        //Set the new title of the cancel button
        [cancelButton setTitle:@"      " forState:UIControlStateNormal];

        // [cancelButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
        [cancelButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"close_icon.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];


    }
}
```

[image]

After Clear tint bar color 
[image]

Please Give me solution ...............
Is Any Hope Please Help me ...........
please help , is there 5 day complete and i don't have any solution

Comment: Are you solve this issue ?

Answer (score 0):

Put this method in you search bar delegates. You need not add image

```
(void) searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar1
{
    [searchBar setShowsCancelButton:YES animated:YES];
}
```

Comment: can you add some more code for me to verify atleast